# How to import hbase-testing-util in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, hbase, pom.xml, hbasetestingutility

These are the dependencies of my project:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.jpmml" % "pmml-evaluator" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.8.2.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.2.0",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "0.98.6-cdh5.3.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.98.6-cdh5.3.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "0.98.6-cdh5.3.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-testing-util" % "0.98.6-cdh5.3.1" % "test",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "0.98.6-cdh5.3.1",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "0.98.6-cdh5.3.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
  "eu.unicredit" %% "hbase-rdd" % "0.5.3"
)
```

I need to use the class `HBaseTestingUtility` to make unit tests on HBase. The problem is that there's probably a bug in SBT 0.13.8 that fail to import the dependecies in the hbase-testing-util pom file. There's a reference for a related bug in SBT 0.13.6 but it should have been solved.

This is the repo I'm working on if you want to inspect the files: https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/libs-release/org/apache/hbase/hbase-testing-util/0.98.6-cdh5.3.1/

Any way to fix this? Any workaround to have this class available? Do I need to import it manually?

Comment: "There's a reference for a related bug in SBT 0.13.6" — link?

Comment: Also, what error message or incorrect behavior do you see with the above code?

Comment: It doesn't import the dependencies in the pom file. It just ignores them. I've spent the day retrieving the dependencies and importing them one by one and I saw progresses but I doesn't seem to reach the end and it always fails to import the dependencies of the libraries I'm including in the project.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "related bug in SBT 0.13.6", please?

Answer (score 0):

The MiniHBaseCluster is on test package of hbase-server, so you'll need to add the "tests" classifier manually, like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-testing-util" % hbaseVersion,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % hbaseVersion,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % hbaseVersion classifier "tests"
)
```